# Typescript: can you use constructor properties within a class's private properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, types

Is it bad practice to use a constructor properties of a class within a variable?  I tried this and was surprised `const name = new Name(time, course);` worked, although I guess it makes sense since an instance of `Eng` needs those constructor properties to be made, then they'd be available to use elsewhere.

```
import { Name } from './Name'

class Eng {
   private _name = new Name(time, course);

   private constructor(time: String, course: String) {} 

   method1(){
      let results = name.convertTrials();

      return results;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example actually has type errors:

```
class Eng {
   private _name = new Name(time, course);
   // Cannot find name 'time'.(2304)
   // Cannot find name 'course'.(2304)

   private constructor(time: string, course: string) {} 
}
```

`time` and `course` are not in scope as far as typescript is concerned. If you want to use constructor parameters, they must be in constructor body.

---

What may be confusing you is that, when compiled, the code runs fine. That is because non-static class properties are moved into the constructor for you, since that is where they would need to be in plain JS.

So your compiled class looks like:

```
// js
class Eng {
    constructor(time, course) {
        this._name = new Name(time, course);
    }
}
```

Which should work without a problem.

But it *is* a problem for Typescript, which believes that the constructor arguments are not in scope outside of the constructor.

---

If you don't need the arguments:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {}
}

class UseFoo {
   private foo = new Foo()
   private constructor() {} 
}
```

Then there isn't anything wrong with your approach.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEByYFsCm0DeAoaXrAPYDsIAXAJwFdgjcSAKABzICMQBLYaIl5ALmmJJb4A5gBpoDZmxy4yJCEl79BQgJSoAvpmx58ANyQkiAFQFgQEGirSbN6UJBgBRYQCEwAEzRbxA3WCIoAPr4iCgAvND4SADucKE0nMhieLLyKgDc3nS+-ig6-BRUtIkKfKTKyTJypUrCVhrQ6Lb2UNDOQgDiuLieGNjZLH4B0MGhvPDIWTnD+aSF1AlcNeXClanLAnVe2DtEABYsEAB0o8jQEVGxE0iLSdLrGd7qjepAA)